# MooTools inject an element at nth position

Tags: mootools

I am trying to inject an element at nth postion. For example, consider that I am having an div and div contains 4 p tag, now I want to inject one more p tag at 2nd position. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You can use the [`Element.inject` API](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element#Element:inject) and do like this:

> **yourNewElement**.inject(**theReferenceElement**, 'after');

That way you specify the the element should be added *after* the reference element you had.

Example:

```js
var p = new Element('p', {
    html: 'Hello!'
});
var second = $$('div p')[2];
p.inject(second, 'after');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.6.0/mootools.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9y8xch4k/

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work.